# Endomorphisms between direct product/sum of algebraic objects?

Tags: commutative-algebra, direct-sum, ring-homomorphism

My motivation is this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) article.

Suppose $R$ be a ring with unity and $M,N$ be $R$-modules.

Take their direct sum/product $P=M \oplus N$. So $P$ is also a $R$-module. Consider the respective rings of endomorphisms $$E_1:=\text{End}_R(M),~ E_2:=\text{End}_R(N),~E_3:=\text{End}_R(P).$$

- What is the relation among $E_1,E_2,E_3$ ? Is $E_3=E_1 \oplus E_2$ ?
- Is the story same for direct product of two algebraic object e.g., for two rings $R,S$, does $\text{End}(R \times S)=\text{End}(R) \times \text{End}(S)$ ?

---

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Homomorphisms) is some information about homomorphisms between direct sums. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a abelian category of algebraic objects $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ with a finite index set $I$. We can equip the direct sum $\oplus A_i$ with projection homomorphism $\pi_j: \oplus A_i \to A_j$ for each $j \in I$ as well as we can equip with coprojection $\alpha_j:A_j \to \oplus A_i$ for each $j \in I$.

Does this help to answer my question 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
In general, it is not true that $E_3=E_1 \oplus E_2$. Perhaps the simplest example is that of a vector space $P$ of dimension $2$ over a field $R$.

---

**Addendum**

$E_{3}$ can be readily described in terms of matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu & \alpha\\
\beta  & \nu
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\mu \in \End_{R}(M)$, $\nu \in \End_{R}(N)$, $\alpha \in \Hom(N, M)$,  $\beta \in \Hom(M, N)$, acting naturally
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu & \alpha\\
\beta  & \nu
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m\\
n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu(m) + \alpha(n)
\\
\beta(m) + \nu(n)
\end{bmatrix}
,
$$
where $m \in M$ and $n \in N$.

So for your relation to hold, you need $\Hom(N, M) =  \Hom(M, N) = 0$. For instance, this is the case when $R = \mathbb{Z}$, and $M, N$ are finite abelian groups of coprime order.

Comment: Thanks. So when does this hold ? At least for groups or rings ?

Comment: You're welcome. The situation is similar for groups and rings. Let me expand a bit my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer. May I just ask one more thing ? Suppose, $P \cong M \oplus N$ instead of $P=M \oplus N$, and also assume the condition $\text{Hom}(M,N)=0=\text{Hom}(M,N)$ as you derived. Is still $E_3=E_1 \oplus E_2$, in this case ?

Comment: @ANG, thanks. With the proper identifications (replacing  equalities by isomorphisms), it's just the same.